# unix manipulate numbers in text file based on values in another file with complicated regex

Tags: regex, unix

I have a nexus file where each line after the header contains a phylogenetic tree in newick format. For each line, I want to find all numbers corresponding to a certain attribute and multiple them based on a line-specific value in another file.

For instance, the first line in the tree file (file1) starts with:

```
tree STATE_0 = ((((1[&theta=0.059198513891606144]:1.8311010331410207 ...
```

with other text following in the basic format of

```
numberA[&theta=numberB]:numberC
```

NumberC for each entry in the line will vary. I want to take each of these numberC, multiply each them by a single value from another file that corresponds to "tree STATE_0" and replace them with these results in the original file.

The second file (file2) is a csv file with one column indicating the tree state number and the second indicating the multiplier for each tree. So for instance, the row corresponding to tree STATE_0 is:

```
0, 0.032
```

So the subset from my first file above would now read:

```
tree STATE_0 = ((((1[&theta=0.059198513891606144]:0.05859523...
```

Constructing the appropriate search expression (grep all cases ]:number) with multiple lines and files involved is beyond my current unix comprehension.

Comment: You want `awk` for this. How big are these files?

Comment: Small files: The tree file is about 8MG, the other is about 900KB